# Rename file name based on folder name through Command prompt

Tags: cmd

"C:\Users\mohammed.h\Desktop\Working\Not Yet Converted to Pdf" I have multiple folders with files in this folder link. Now I want rename all files inside the folder with based on folder name. Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to write a small batch script (.bat file) and run that at command prompt. Here is an excellent intro on how to rename files in a windows environment using the "ren" command ... http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/z-ren1.html

Here also a post on how to get the current folder name
https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command

Answer (score 0):

Get the current directory with the Tina's answer.

`for %%* in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~nx*`

Then, you just have to `ren file.ext %CurrDirName%.ext`.

Don't forget to `@echo off` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%* in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~nx*
echo %CurrDirName%

ren 00__G.pdf 00_%CurrDirName%_G.pdf
ren 00__Z.pdf 00_%CurrDirName%_Z.pdf
```

-In drive `D:\` I have a directory `HOME`

-In directory `home` have file `00__G.pdf`

- This syntax rename file `00__G.pdf` to `00_HOME_G.pdf`
- This syntax rename file `00__Z.pdf` to `00_HOME_Z.pdf`